# Python: How to only pass needed arguments into function from a dictionary?

Tags: python, function, arguments

Assume now I have a well-defined function

```
def f1(a):
    ...
```

and i can not change its definition. Now I want to call it with a argument from a dictionary

```
D={ 'a':1 , 'b':2}
```

If I call it like

```
f1(**D)
```

there will be a syntax error (because b is not defined in f1). My question is if I can find a smart way to let the function to find the argument it needed only?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [On topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and [... the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) apply here.

Comment: What is needed from the dicitonary for you function are you going to use the entire dicitonary? Showing what actions you want your function to perform would help greatly

Comment: What parameter type does the function expect?  What argument from the dictionary did you want to pass?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use [`inspect.getargspec`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#inspect.getargspec):

```
d = {'a': 5, 'b': 6, 'c': 7}
def f(a,b):
    return a + b

f(*[d[arg] for arg in inspect.getargspec(f).args])
```

which gives `11`.

---

Thanks Eugene, `getargspec` is legacy, instead you should use [`getfullargspec`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#inspect.getfullargspec) which has the same usage in this case.

Comment: `Deprecated since version 3.0: Use getfullargspec() for an updated API that is usually a drop-in replacement, but also correctly handles function annotations and keyword-only parameters.`

Comment: @EugeneYarmash THanls

Answer (score 1):

You could get the argument names from the function's [code object](https://docs.python.org/3.7/reference/datamodel.html#index-55), then lookup the values for them in the dictionary:

```
>>> def f(a):
...     b = 2
...     return a + b
...
>>> D = {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}
>>> nargs = f.__code__.co_argcount
>>> varnames = f.__code__.co_varnames
>>> f(*(D[arg] for arg in varnames[:nargs]))
3
```

Answer (score -3):

Here is an example of function that got a dictionary and use only the 'b' key :

```
In [14]: def f1(mydict):
    ...:     return mydict['b']
    ...: 

In [15]: x={'a': 1, 'b':2}

In [16]: f1(x)
Out[16]: 2
```

Comment: I did not downvote, but you should not use `dict` as variable name because it shadows the built-in